# Excel: Computing Cumulative GPA using Lookup Formulae

Tags: excel, product, vlookup

I have arranged my course grades in the spreadsheet here: [Degree Audit](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8eqottp7m5h9gq3/Degree%20Audit.xlsx)

I am attempting to multiply the credit-hour values in B2:B12 by the GPA measurements in I3:I15 by matching the letter grades in D3:D12 to their corresponding values in H3:H15.

See cell E3 in spreadsheet linked below for my best attempt using a VLOOKUP formula and multiplication - I'm close, but it's still returning #N/A.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: u can click on the 'tick' besides the answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

in your `D3` cell you have "A" without space, but in your  `H4` cell you have "A " with space. You need to delete the space after "A". 
And also you need to modify VLOOKUP by adding ",0" to the end:

`=$B3*VLOOKUP(D3,$H$3:$I$15,2,0)`

Comment: Thanks a ton! I had a huge hunch that it had something to do with formatting, but this makes a lot more sense. Much appreciated.